# Dell PowerEdge R610 with external graphic card white screens when I powerload the gpu

Tags: gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, dell-poweredge

I have a Dell PowerEdge R610 and 1 year ago I made it for gaming, so I had put a graphic card on it (Nvidia GTX 1050TI). The idea is that this gpu doesn't fit in the 1U case and as far as I know it can't power my gpu from the 16x riser (and this gpu doesn't have an external power port), so I am running it with a mining 16X to 1X riser. It ran perfectly for a year and now, when the GPU is under 'big' loads, I suddenly get black or white screens, with the server fans increasing their RPM drastically. I tried to change the riser (I thought that is the problem), but it does the same. I can't test de gpu in other pc, and I can't try the gpu in other PCI port (the server has 2 8x PCI ports, but I broke one of them). The server is running normally, like I can do normal stuff on it, but I can't do gaming (I can play only league of legends, the other games have bigger GPU requirements, so they are bringing bigger loads on the GPU and it crashes). P.S. The mining riser power is coming from an external power supply.
I tried this setup with a 100% good graphic card and it does the same.

Any ideas?
[These are some photos with the setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPMoN.jpg)
[Photo 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FwFC.jpg)
[Photo 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXJJB.jpg)
[Photo 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxLFP.jpg)

Comment: Maybe a heat problem?

Comment: @harrymc It can't be a heat problem. I can do normal stuff on the server for the whole day, but when I open a game, it instantly crashes...

Comment: Has the Nvidia driver been updated about when the problem began?

Comment: Yes, it was. I think I figured it out. I changed the PSU and now it is working fine.